# How can I alphabatize the word TRUE in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

When I type the word TRUE in an excel cell, it centers it and when I try to alphabetize a column which includes TRUE it puts it at the bottom.  How can I make excel treat the word true just as a word?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the result of Excel seeing the word `TRUE` as a logical value, not simply text. Then Excel is following it's sort order as below, which results in `TRUE` going to the bottom.

1. Numbers - Excel sorts numbers from the smallest negative number to
   the largest positive number.
2. Alphanumeric - Excel sorts alphanumeric text left to right,
   character by character.
3. **Logical Values - Excel places FALSE before TRUE.**
4. Error Values - Excel treats all error values as equals.
5. Blanks - Excel always places blanks last.

To resolve this, place a single apostrophe before the word, `'TRUE`, and it will not be recognized as a logical value.